# Htaccess one or two level directory but not for js or css

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I tried using this code:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/([0-9a-zA-Z]+) results.php?property_type=$1&city=$2 [NC,L]
```

I want to redirect all of my property types and city.
Example:

```
domain.com/apartment/doha
```

But it seems that it is now working, the js, css, images or any includes are returning an error.

What is the best approach for this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing fix your rule's regex by having this in root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/?$ results.php?city=$1&property_type=$2 [QSA,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/?$ results.php?city=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Then add this in the `<head>` section of your page's HTML:

```
<base href="/" />
```

so that every relative URL is resolved from that URL and not the current page's URL.

Comment: Hi @anubhava,
Thanks! it works! but I have one more problem.
I changed it to domain.com/doha/apartment 
But I need to be **domain.com/doha** too

but i have a rewrite rules like this:
RewriteRule ^privacy-policy privacy-policy.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^commercial results.php?page=commercial [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^buy results.php?forwhat=sale [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^rent results.php?forwhat=rent [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^results results.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^agents agent.php [NC,L]

it conflicts with the rules you gave me. What should I do with this?
Thanks!

Comment: Keep those specific rules before my suggested rule. And also see updated rules.